# How can I troubleshooting about w3wp

Tags: c#, iis

I got this error message saying :

> Failed to delete file c:\TP99Files\abc.log. Error: Access to the path 'c:\TP99Files\abc.log' is denied. Category: AService Priority: 10 EventId: 8205 Severity: Error Title: Machine: AAServer App Domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132042928176410958 ProcessId: 15780 Process Name: c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe Thread Name: ThreadForDelete Win32 ThreadId:17264 Extended Properties:

I got many error messages like above

How can I debugging this issue?

Comment: IIS itself won't use that folder. So you should review the code of your web apps to find out who is the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to delete file c:\TP99Files\abc.log. Error: Access to the path 'c:\TP99Files\abc.log' is denied. Category

As far as I know, the access denied means the your IIS application pool doesn't have the enoguh permission to delete the log file.

I suggest you could follow below steps to set the enough permission.

1.Right click the TP99Files folder, click property and find the security.

[image]

2.Click the Edit button and then Add button.

3.Click the Locations button and make sure that you select your computer and enter IIS AppPool{yourapplicationpool} in the Enter the object names to select: text box.

[image]

4.Click the Check Names button and click OK.

5.Then you set the enough permission to let the IIS to delete the file.